# Android DiffUtil :: onBindViewHolder returning the position removed from the list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I am trying to remove Items from adapter when Item is clicked
The display is doing the right thing 
but when I click the last item, I get **IndexOutOfBound Exception**

my diff utils the below

```
class ItemListDiffUtilCallBack(val oldList: List<Item?>,
                                     val newList: List<Item?>) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean
            = oldList[oldItemPosition]?.Id == newList[newItemPosition]?.Id

    override fun getOldListSize() = oldList.size

    override fun getNewListSize() = newList.size

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean
            = oldList[oldItemPosition]?.isEnrolled == newList[newItemPosition]?.isEnrolled

    override fun getChangePayload(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Any? {
        return super.getChangePayload(oldItemPosition, newItemPosition)
    }
}
```

this is how I'm updating the list where the newList have an Item removed from it.

**The display is removing the Item with the default as intended**

```
 private fun updateList(newList: MutableList<Item?>) {
        val oldList = itemList.toMutableList()
        itemList.clear()
        itemList.addAll(newList)
        val result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(ItemListDiffUtilCallBack(oldList, itemList))
        result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this@ItemRecyclerViewAdapter)
    }
```

when the **onBindViewHolder** get trigger after **dispatchUpdatesTo**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        if (holder is ItemViewHolder) {
            val Item = itemList[position] 
            holder.setItem(Item)

            val myButtonListener = View.OnClickListener {
                itemList[position]?.Id?.let { Id ->
                    listener.onItemClick(Id)
                }
            }
            holder.setButtonClickListener(myButtonListener )
        } 
    }
```

> val Item = itemList[position] **itemList** still have the size before the update.

And when I click the last Item to remove it,

> itemList[position]?.Id?.let {   **itemList[position]** the position return the last Item of the old list so I get the **IndexOutOfBound Exception**

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think after adding or removing items to/from list you have to call "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();"

Comment: May not be the issue but your `areContentsTheSame()` should be `oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]`, assuming `Item` is a `data class`

Comment: @MohamedMohsin same thing

Answer (score 0):

If you are deleting an item you have to submit a new list to your adapter.
Your adapter has to inherit from `:ListAdapter<T,K>(YourDiffcallback())`

```
adapter.submitList(list)
```